How to show $\partial_t h =\Delta h -2|M_{ij}|^2 +rh$ in Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces
Pictures below is from Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces  (  237- 262  of this), I want to calculate the red line.
First, we consider the 2-dimensional normalized Ricci flow
$$
\partial_t g_{ij}=(r-R)g_{ij}
$$
where $R=2K$ is scalar curvature, $K$ is sectional curvature, and $r$ is the average value of $R$. Therefore, we have
$$
\partial_t R=\Delta R +R^2 -rR
$$
Let $\Delta f=R-r$, then, there is
$$
\partial_t f =\Delta f + rf -b
$$
where $b=\int|Df |^2 d\mu/\int d\mu$ is a function of time.
After some calculation, the red line is equal to show
$$
R|Df|^2 +2g^{ij}D_i(\Delta f) D_j f  =\Delta (|Df|^2) - 2|D^2 f|^2
\tag{1}
$$
The key is to calculate $\Delta (|Df|^2)$, I have
$$
\Delta (|Df|^2) =2|D^2 f|^2 +2g^{ab}g^{ij} D_aD_bD_if D_jf+\Delta(g^{ij}) D_i f D_j f
\tag{2}
$$
I calculate
$$
2g^{ab}g^{ij} D_aD_bD_if D_jf 
= 
-2g^{ij}g^{kl} R_{aail}D_jf D_kf+2 g^{ij} D_i(\Delta f)D_j f
=
2 g^{ij} D_i(\Delta f)D_j f
\tag{3}
$$
By normalized coordinate , there is
$$
g_{ij}(x)= \delta_{ij} - \frac{1}{3}R_{ikjl} x^k x^l +O(|x|^3)
\tag{4}
$$
therefore, I have
$$
\Delta(g^{ij}) = \frac{2}{3} R^{ij}
\tag{5}
$$
So, I have
$$
\Delta(g^{ij}) D_i f D_j f=\frac{R}{3}|Df|^2
\tag{6}
$$
Now, (2) become
$$
\Delta (|Df|^2) =2|D^2 f|^2 +2 g^{ij} D_i(\Delta f)D_j f  +\frac{R}{3}|Df|^2 
\tag{7}
$$
From (7) and (1), there is
$$
R|Df|^2 =\frac{R}{3}|Df|^2 
$$
which obviously be wrong.
I've been doing it for two mornings, you know that the actual process is much more complicated, and I really can't find out what I did wrong. Help me, thanks.




While I was eating, it occurred to me that (1) might be wrong. Maybe, I calculate $\partial_t (\Delta f)$ wrong. So, I calculate  it  again  tomorrow morning.

First, (5) is wrong. I confused the tensor and the component. In (4), $g_{ij}$ is the component of $g$ under normal coordinate. In (5), we using abstract index, so, $\Delta(g^{ij})$ is $\Delta(g^{ij}\partial_i\otimes\partial_j)$. Since $\nabla g=0$, there is $\Delta (g^{ij})=0$.
Besides, (3) is wrong, since I use a wrong  formula. The right version is
$$
2g^{ab}g^{ij} D_aD_bD_if D_jf 
= 
2D(\Delta f) \cdot  Df +R|Df|^2
$$
Now, the (2) become
$$
\Delta (|Df|^2)=2|D^2 f|^2+2D(\Delta f) \cdot Df +R|Df|^2
$$
which imply (1).
Beside, no matter treat $\Delta f$ as $g^{ij}D_iD_j f$ or
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g}} D_i (g^{ij} \sqrt{\det g} D_j f)$,
the results of $\partial_t(\Delta f)$ are same.  I doubt that these two expressions are equivalent. For example, using $\nabla g=0$,  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g}} D_i (g^{ij} \sqrt{\det g} D_j f)$  becomes $g^{ij}D_iD_j f$. is it ?

You can see $\Delta f = g^{ij}\nabla_i \nabla_j f$ by consider $divX = tr (\nabla X)$ and the second one is by $\Delta f = div (grad f)$ which both expression are equivalent as definition for $div$ is equivalent. The simplest way to check is use normal coordinate.

@mikeqwertyuiop I know $\Delta f = div (grad f)$. But sometimes I always get stupid, maybe because I don't have a solid foundation.  ;-)

Its okay, I am a beginner studying this subject :)
